# how can i take over mouse control in a jitsi meet screen share session with a partner?

Tags: mouse, jitsi-meet

How can i take over mouse control in a jitsi meet screen share session?
I do not see any button or option to activate this. Can anybody tell me if this is possible

Comment: Currently not supported. You're talking about remote control feature and has been removed from jitsi permanently. See the discussion here https://community.jitsi.org/t/howto-use-jitsi-meet-to-remotely-control-another-participants-shared-screen/48910/18

Answer (score 0):

That's a pity - it is an integral part of working together (pair programming, brain storming, collaboration in general, teacher show pupil and so on). Both Zoom and GotoMeeting allows it and with a proper 2 or 3 way handshake/approval it can be done securely.